# When using IBO/EBO, program only works when I call glBindBuffer to bind the IBO/EBO AFTER creation of the VAO

Tags: c++, c, opengl, vbo, vao

For some reason, this program only works when I bind the IBO/EBO **again**, after I create the VAO. I read online, *and multiple SO posts*, that glBindBuffer only binds the current buffer, and that it does **not** attach it the the VAO. I thought the glVertexAttribPointer is the function that attached the data to the VAO.

```
float points[] = {

   -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, // top left      = 0
    0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, // top right     = 1
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom right  = 2
   -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom left   = 3

};

GLuint elements[] = {

    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,
};

// generate vbo (point buffer)
GLuint pb = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &pb);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pb);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// generate element buffer object (ibo/ebo)
GLuint ebo = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// generate vao
GLuint vao = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pb);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);


glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo); // when I bind buffer again, it works


glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

If I did not have the second glBindBuffer, the program crashes. All I want to know is why I have to call glBindBuffer again, after I create the VAO, when calling glBindBuffer only makes the buffer the active buffer for other functions.

[Pastebin (FULL CODE)](http://pastebin.com/41dn2Uu5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the order of your initial calls. The `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding is part of the VAO state. Look at this sequence:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint vao = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

Since the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding is part of the VAO state, the `glBindVertexArray()` call at the end of the sequence will establish the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer binding that is part of the VAO `vao` you're binding. Which, since you just created `vao`, is `0`. So at the end of this sequence, you have no element array buffer bound.

Or, looking at it from a different direction, when you make the `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo)` call at the start, VAO `0` is bound. So this binding becomes part of the state of VAO `0`. Then, when you bind a different VAO `vao`, you lose the binding, and it is replaced with the binding that is part of the state of VAO `vao`.

To make this work as you expected, you need to make the initial `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding **after** you bind the VAO. It then becomes part of the VAO state, and will be established again every time you bind the VAO later:

```
GLuint vao = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you look at the specification, the Vertex Array Object state does not include the Element Buffer Object.

Indeed, enabling the VAO does not set the element bindibg point.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but this is completely wrong. The element buffer binding **is** part of the VAO state.

Comment: Maybe I need to read again the OpenGL specification... Recently I cannot write a correct answer about OpenGL. Sob.

Comment: If you have for example the OpenGL 3.3 spec document handy, check table 6.5 on page 281. The table is named "Vertex Array Object State", and contains `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING`.